# How to make EXPLAIN SELECT statements return the original table names instead of their aliases?

Tags: php, mysql, select, pdo, explain

I have a SQL query of this format:

`SELECT * FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id;`

I would like, for any given SQL SELECT query unknown in advance to know which tables were used to run it. So I thought I would use the EXPLAIN SELECT statement for that.

My issue is that the `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id;` query returns "t1" and "t2" as table names. I need it to give me the original table names, so table1 and table2 respectively. Now, I understand that it is not possible [according to this old report](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=24693).

However, I need to make this work somehow. I don't really want to run some REGEX on the query (unless you have one in mind that will undoubtedly include all scenarios of how tables can be used in a query, no matter how unstandardized it is).

I'm ready to hear all the possibilities that you might have in mind, it does not have to use the EXPLAIN SELECT as long as I can get all my original table names that were used in an unknown SELECT query. I don't care about the rest of the information provided by EXPLAIN SELECT, I just need the table names.

In case you want to propose a solution that is outside MySQL's scope, I am using PHP as the main platform to execute these requests with PDO (however, the queries are executed directly, they are **not** prepared statements).

Comment: This is done in case there are self-joins, so you can tell which instance of the table it's referring to. I don't think there's any way to customize the output.

Comment: You can get rid of the aliases in the query.

Comment: @Barmar That's an option for sure, but how would I do that if I don't know the queries beforehand? In fact, I don't even know if there is an alias to be found. I would have no issues at all to get rid of the aliases in the query as long as it still works afterwards

Comment: there's https://github.com/greenlion/PHP-SQL-Parser but as soon as you start parsing sql you are going to have problems where msyql starts supporting something new that your parser doesn't

Comment: Why are you trying to explain a query that you don't know beforehand? What are you going to do with the result?

Comment: I want to keep track of the tables that were read for all the queries that are being executed from PHP. The reason I say I don't know them beforehand is that they are already hardcoded in the code, there are thousands of them and I can't edit them one by one to remove the aliases.

Comment: A workaround can be using regex on the SQL query itself in PHP, so selecting the text string after `FROM` or `JOIN` (and there may be some other cases but this will catch almost all instances)

Comment: @ysth I will be considering this option, it looks good enough for what I'm trying to do thanks. @Martin I have been trying to make a regex to catch the strings after FROM or JOINS, but I'm not an expert with regex. So far I came up with this: `/(?:FROM|JOIN)\s+(\w+)/g`, but it does not work when there are more than one table selected after the FROM.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table1 t1, table2 JOIN table3 ON table2.id = table3.t2_id` here is just one example of a query that will not work with the regex above. This is why I'm reticent using regexes here. But I like that SQL parser, it seems quite capable.

Comment: @PlugN yeah thinking on the fly I hadn't considered comma separated tables as proper syntax should not use lazy comma separation.

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for can get really complex, because a table reference in SQL can be a [view](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/views.html), or a [common table expression](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html), or a [derived table subquery](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/parenthesized-query-expressions.html).

Any of those may be a [`JOIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html) of multiple tables, or a [`UNION`/`INTERSECT`/`EXCEPT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-operations.html) of multiple queries.

It can even have *no* base table at all if it's a subquery that selects a tuple, or a [`VALUES` statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/values.html).

I don't think there's a way to do what you want with regular expressions unless you're satisfied with a very reduced subset of SQL queries. You'd need a full-blown SQL parser to track the base table(s) per table reference.